# SwiftUI - how to detect long press on Button?

Tags: swiftui, watchos

I have a Button where when it gets pressed, it performs some actions. But I would like to modify the same Button to detect a longer press, and perform a different set of processes. How do I modify this code to detect a long press?

```
Button(action: {
              // some processes

            }) {
              Image(systemName: "circle")
                .font(.headline)
                .opacity(0.4)

            }
```

Answer (score 15):

Here is possible variant (tested with Xcode 11.2 / iSO 13.2).

```
Button("Demo") {
    print("> tap")
}
.simultaneousGesture(LongPressGesture().onEnded { _ in
    print(">> long press")
})
```

Comment: This is the best solution I've seen. However, be aware that the button press action is still triggered upon releasing the button. In my use case this didn't matter.

Comment: I like this solution, however it still triggers the button tap as mentioned. Is there a way to exclusively detect tap of the button or long press? In this case, it should recognize the long press before tap.

Comment: It's a nice solution but how ever it disabled scrolling in my scrollview

Answer (score 9):

Daniel Wood's comment is correct in both statements. First, it is the cleanest solution. For the second, there is a straightforward workaround.

```
struct ContentView: View {
  @State private var didLongPress = false

  var body: some View {
    Button("Demo") {
      if self.didLongPress {
        self.didLongPress = false
          doLongPressThing()
      } else {
          doTapThing()
      }
    }.simultaneousGesture(
      LongPressGesture().onEnded { _ in self.didLongPress = true }
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey Andrew! Thanks for this workaround. Do we have any another solution in 2022? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This way you can also recognize a long press on a button and distinguish it from a simple tap gesture:

```
        Button(action: {}) {
            Text("Push")
        }
        .simultaneousGesture(TapGesture().onEnded { _ in
            print("simultaneousGesture TapGesture")
        })
        .simultaneousGesture(LongPressGesture().onEnded { _ in
            print("simultaneousGesture LongPressGesture")
        })
```

Answer (score 1):

As of iOS 15 you should use a Menu with a primaryAction