# OnLongPressGesture release action (SwiftUI)

Tags: swiftui, gesture

I see there is a .onLongPressGesture(minimumDuration:maximumDistance:pressing:perform:).

However there isnt enough documentation for me to understand how to perform an action when the user releases the button.

A good example to understand what I am talking about is when you hold down a button to start recording a video and let go to stop the recording.

```
.onLongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 0.5, maximumDistance: 100, pressing: {}, perform: {} )
```

Comment: What if you just add `onTapGesture` to the `Button` in addition to `onLongPressGesture`? Also, I believe the `label` parameter is a `Label`, not a string. I believe you're looking for `Button(_:action:)`.

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/60465960/12299030? Or this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/61723144/12299030?

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61784292/14351818

Comment: @West1 not relevant to the question

Comment: @BestFromAbove It was certainly relevant when I posted it (before you edited your question to exclude your incorrect use of `Button`).

Comment: @West1 Pointing out an incorrect label argument has no relevance to the question of an onLongPressGesture modifier.

Comment: @BestFromAbove 1) I regret trying to help you, lol. 2) Your code was never going to work as it was, so pointing this out was *absolutely* relevant. 3) In the future, you should test your code in Xcode before pasting it into Stack Overflow so you avoid making another stupid mistake.

Comment: @BestFromAbove Right. Well, have a nice day, pal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to this is by calling the identifier like this.

1. Created a state that tracks if the user has pressed the button

```
@State var hasPressed = false
```

2. On the pressing parameter, use the state to perform an action depending on if the user is pressing the button or not.

```
.onLongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 0.5, maximumDistance: 100, pressing: {
                            pressing in
                            self.hasPressed = pressing
                            if pressing {action1}
                            if !pressing {action2}
                        }, perform: {})
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed similar functionality but I could not achieve it with the pressing parameter. I solved it by sequencing 2 gesture recognizers:

```
struct MyView: View {
    @GestureState var isPressing = false

    Image("action-icon")
        .gesture(LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 0.01)
            .sequenced(before: LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: .infinity))
            .updating($isPressing) { value, state, transaction in
                switch value {
                case .second(true, nil):
                    state = true
                    startVideoRecording()

                default: 
                    break
                }
            })
        .onChange(of: isPressing) { value in
            if value == false {
                stopVideoRecording()
            }
        }
}
```