# Confusing button-actions in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-button

Here is some SwiftUI code in a running app I am working on:

```
    Button(action: action) {
        Image(systemName: img)
            .imageScale(.large)
    }
    .simultaneousGesture(LongPressGesture().onEnded { _in
        playLngPress = true
        showingFlag = true
    })
```

My question is about the relationship between the chunk of code executed when making a long-press on the button and the chunk of code executed when making a simple tap. I first noticed that when making a long-press, the action (for a simple tap) was also executed along side.
Though I do not think this is how it should be, I made a work-around to have things go my way.

More recently (after moving to iOS 15, though I am not 100% sure this is the Reason) I noticed that the action for the tap is not always performed when making a long-press.

Can anyone precisely explain how this is working ?

Comment: It is working as it did in iOS 14 for me, as expected. I presume you did something like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62480287/7129318) to get an OR instead of an AND with your gestures. The reason it works this way is simple. You put a `.simultaneousGesture` on it, meaning BOTH at the same time.

Comment: Thanks for your short and clear explanation about the AND/OR. I tried replacing ".simultaneousGesture(LongPressGesture().onEnded { _in" by this: ".onLongPressGesture(perform: {". But the long press is  no longer detected at all.

Comment: @Yrb. Your explanation misses one detail for my problem. Why is it that the tap action is not always called along with the long-press action (when using simultaneousGesture)?

Comment: As I said in the beginning, I am not seeing that issue with the code you posted. If you are having an issue, then there must be something more on your end.

Comment: Well, that may be true. But what should I provide for you to see?
I can say that though it mostly work as it should, when I make the first long-press it happens that the the tap action is not called. I do not know why.

Comment: A [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You are claiming it happens, but have not provided a minimal example that can be built and run that shows it. You will be amazed how many times writing an MRE gives you the answer.

Comment: OK you are right. I will try to create an MRE and see.